# java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: jaxb, mule, jaxb2, mule-studio

i have created a flow, in which i am converting a jaxb object to xml using mulexml:jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer,  i am getting the following jaxb exception

```
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:328)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:254)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.writeObject(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:542)
```

following is my flow code

```
<component doc:name="Java">             
    <method-entry-point-resolver>
        <include-entry-point method="findJatoXmlByDate"/>
    </method-entry-point-resolver>  
    <spring-object bean="jatoReadDAO">
    </spring-object>
</component>
<logger message="after java ================   #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
<logger message="after splitting #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<mulexml:jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer name="ObjectToSmartxml" jaxbContext-ref="jatoJaxbContext"/>
<collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
```

i have tried to put @xmlSeeAlso on my Jaxb class but still i am getting the same exception.
following is my jaxb class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "commentOrAltCommentOrAtt"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "JatuXML")
public class JATUXML {
```

Comment: Can you add a few more lines of logs? I'd like to see what the payload is "after splitting"

Comment: non of logger are showing any message here.

Comment: can you change the level to error to make sure they log?

Comment: i have resolved this error, i was getting this error not because of marshaling, it was because of collection-splitter, here when i added collection aggregator, flow works fine.

Comment: You should answer your own question with the solution so that the question does not go unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved this error, i was getting this error not because of marshaling, it was because of collection-splitter, here when i added collection aggregator, flow works fine.